# zlib.h versus zlib.net

Tags: c#, zlib

I have made a compression in c/c++ (NO UNDER THE CLR) using the library zlib.h, and it works great. the functions that I use deflate() and inflate(). 
Now the file compressed by the c application, I want to decompress it with the zlib.net application, using c#, but I do not manage to get it working. When trying to decompress it, I get the error of the magic number, a number used by an specific application in the header. Does anyone know how to get through this problem, or if someone can give me an example of the inflate()/deflate() functionality in .net
for more info on how I have done my compression, is similar to the one in the link http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html

Also, can any one advice me of a good lib to perform compression in both c++ and .net,
Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There's some discussion on this here:  [Zlib-compatible compression streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70347/zlib-compatible-compression-streams)

I think Boost may work with zlib to add the header information:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html